# Get the SiteUrl in UrlToken in a Sharepoint 2007 custom action

Tags: sharepoint

In a custom action *UrlAction* element I need to get the *SiteUrl*

As described in many sources I can achieve this by inserting *{SiteUrl}*. So my would look like this:

The Site Url is: `http://sharepoint-server/sites/xyz`

```
<UrlAction Url="{SiteUrl}/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder={SiteUrl}%2fLists%2fMyList%2fMyFolder&FilterField1=SomeFilterField&FilterValue1=SomeFilterValue">
```

Unfortunately this is not working for some reason. When I insert the SiteUrl manually it works as expected. So it seems the SiteUrl is not substituted correctly.

Anybody got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at least the {SiteUrl} token is replaced only once.

As ~site is subsituted by the web url as well, I used both tags:

```
<UrlAction Url="~site/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder={SiteUrl}%2fLists%2fMyList%2fMyFolder&FilterField1=SomeFilterField&FilterValue1=SomeFilterValue">
```

This way it is working!